# How to mock accept method from python socket?

Tags: sockets, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to mock a `socket.accept()` to use with pytest.

My code:

```py
    [...]
    def reading_socket(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
            s.listen()
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            with conn:
                print("Client data:", addr)
                while True:
                    data_encoded = conn.recv(1024)
                    if not data_encoded:
                        break
                    data = func(data_encoded)
                    conn.close()
                    conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        return data
```

And my test:

```py
@patch("socket.socket")
def test_reading_socket(mock_socket):
    mock_socket.return_value.accept.return_value = ("foo", "bar")
    result = reading_socket()
```

I can't get return or side_effect to `accept`. I always get this error:

```bash
>           conn, addr = s.accept()
E           ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```